# Download .exe file with SailsJS - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, exe, sails.js, node-webkit

I have created a small application using **Node-WebKit**. So I want to write a backend service in **SailsJS** which will help me download an exe of my application from a remote server. I would like to know how I can write a service to download an .exe file to local disk when the remote server location is specified.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends a bit on where the executable is.  But basically you'll just read that file and write it to the response stream.  This is most efficiently done by piping the file stream into the response stream. Something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filePath = 'path/to/your/file.exe';
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/exe',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
});

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
readStream.pipe(response);
```

It should be noted that many systems will block your exe from being run after downloading it from the web, so this might not be the best distribution model for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me how this will work? 
Right now for testing I am trying to download a file that is locally in my system which is in one drive(C) to another drive (D). For that how the code will work?

Comment: That code will have to be part of the Sails app you described.  If you make a Sails app,  you put that code into one of the controller actions.

Comment: I tried the method that you have provided. But I am not getting the same .exe file whose path I have provided.

Comment: Post  your updated code, you're probably not creating the path properly but it's hard to tell by guessing.

Comment: Sorry . It was my mistake. This method works.
I just had to give an **<a> tag** for downloading. 
Thanks @Paul